# Pressing "Enter" key should click a specific button in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a page with several buttons. On page load if I hit "Enter" key, it clicks on a specific button. I would like to have a different button clicked when the user hits "Enter" on page load.

I have tried this:

HTML:

```
<button type="submit" (click)="submitted()" id="submit-btn"><span #defaultButton>Submit</span> </button>
```

Comment: I have tried this:

HTML:
<button type="submit" (click)="submitted()" id="submit-btn"><span #defaultButton>Submit</span> </button>

TS:

@ViewChild('defaultButton') defaultButtonE1:ElementRef;

public ngAfterViewInit() {
        setTimeout(()=>{ 
            this.defaultButtonE1.nativeElement.focus();
          });
  }

Comment: post your code in question.

Answer (score 1):

You've tried correctly to configure your button as `type="submit"`.

The problem is with all other buttons in your view. You need to configure them as `type="button"` in order to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@HostListener` to detect document events and override them.

```
  @ViewChild('defaultButton') defaultButton : ElementRef;

  @HostListener('document:keydown.enter', ['$event']) onKeydownHandler(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.defaultButton.nativeElement.click();
  }
```

Here is a live example of your code with it:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vynxve

A good place to read about `HostListener` and `HostBinding`:

https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/custom-directives/hostlistener-and-hostbinding/

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="submit" (keyup.enter)="submitted()" id="submit-btn"><span #defaultButton>Submit</span> </button>
```